# Find the most significant corner of a skeleton and segment the skeleton at that corner

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting, scikit-image

I have images of ore seams which I have first skeletonised (medial axis multiplied by the distance transform), then extracted corners (see the green dots). It looks like this:

[image: Skeleton Corners]

The problem is to find a turning point and then segment the seam by separating the seam at the turning point. Not all skeletons have turning points, some are quite linear, and the turning points can be in any orientation. But the above image shows a seam which does have a defined turning point. Other examples of turning points look like (using ASCII): "- /- _". "X" turning points don't really exist.

I've tried a number of methods including downsampling the image, curve fitting, k-means clustering, corner detection at various thresholds and window sizes, and I haven't figured it out yet. (I'm new to to using scikit)

The technique must be able to give me some value which I can use heuristically determine whether there is a turning point or not.

What I'd like to do is to do some sort of 2 line ("piecewise"?) regression and find an intersection or some sort of rotated polynomial regression, then determine if a turning point exists, and if it does exist, the best coordinate that represents the turning point. Here is my work in progress: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/40eda19e50dec671126a

From there, I learned that a watershed segmentation with appropriate label coordinates should be able to segment the skeleton.

I found this resource: [Fit a curve for data made up of two distinct regimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19955686/fit-a-curve-for-data-made-up-of-two-distinct-regimes)

But I wasn't able to figure out to apply it my current situation. More importantly there's no way for me to guess a-priori what the initial coefficients are for the fitting function since the skeletons can be in any orientation.